# Google Cloud DNS CNAME aliasing to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dns

The Google Cloud Storage documentation states :

> If you want the test.example.com to serve the same content as is served from www.example.com, add a CNAME record that aliases "test" to "www". A separate bucket is not needed in this scenario.
>   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration?hl=en

With the alias CNAME in place (on Google Cloud DNS) the following error is being thrown by the Cloud Storage :

```
<Error>
 <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
 <Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>   
</Error>
```

Has this behavior changed and the documentation hasn't been updated ? Or are there any additional steps required to make this work ?

Comment: I am looking into it and I will get back to you with more information when I have it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same issue. As confirmed with the engineering team,  CNAME > CNAME > bucket is not possible which is the opposite of what the documentation is saying. I was able to file a request for the documentation change which should be modified soon. As a workaround, creating a new bucket with the subdomain will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks George. This seemed like a nice feature :P, guess that isn't as simple as adding a ServerAlias ;-)

Answer (score 0):

CNAME is equivalent to your sub domain. Please use the step by step procedure from Google Cloud Platform Documentation. See below:

https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart